# Passing json via ajax to Page OnGet method

Tags: json, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I have a datagrid, which is populated with records using PartnersController's Index Action.
When selected row is changed, I want to show details for selected partner (new page with detail data).

Inside my Partners\Index.cshtml I have script to open new page, with one parameter for partner id (ppId).

```
//...
var obj = { ppId: data.Id };

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(myJSON); // PRINTS: {"ppId":10531} ---- OK!

var url = '/Partners/Details';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.name);
        window.location = url;  // --- redirection ok!
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

And this is my targeted Partners\Details.cshtml Razor page:

```
public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet([FromBody]dynamic param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Details...PPID:'" + param + "'"); // PRINTS Details...PPID:'' //param is null!
    }
}
```

So, I'm being redirected to Details page which is fine (url is localhost/Partners/Details), but param is null, and have zero idea how to get it.

xhr GET request params looks like this:

[[image: xhr GET request params looks like this[1]]

In this Details page, my plan is to get partner id via OnGet method, and then use it for DevExtreme DataGrid DataSource Load parameter

```
.DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("Partners").LoadAction("Details").LoadParams(new { PartnerId = ppId }).Key("Id"));
```

At the end, is this whole approach ok?

I'm using .Net core 3.1

Comment: I managed to pass parameter with a single line in JS: window.location('/Partners/Details?ppId=' + data.Id). And in Details Page: OnGet(string ppId). But, I would still want to know if I can use JSON and AJAX approach.

Comment: For general help on working with JSON in Razor Pages, see this: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/web-api. For help on modelbinding within a PageModel, see this: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding. DevExtreme also provide docs on what you appear to be attempting: https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNetCore/401221/devextreme-based-controls/concepts/bind-controls-to-data/razor-page-handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [FromBody] in the Get request due to which model binding will try to bind the values from the body, not the query string. Also, as a good practice, you should never ever have [FromBody] in the GET request - it is technically not possible to send the data in a GET request.

Please try this:

```
public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet([FromQuery]string param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Details...PPID:'" + param + "'"); // PRINTS Details...PPID:'' //param is null!
    }
}
```

Also, your client code is not quite right. You should pass the parameter as a query string. See below

```
var obj = { ppId: data.Id }; // This is not required

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(myJSON); // PRINTS: {"ppId":10531} ---- OK!

var url = '/Partners/Details?param=' + data.Id; // Pass the id as a query string

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
       alert(result.name);
       window.location = url;  // --- redirection ok!
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
 });
```